# how to split a string into an array using last occurrence of '-' using regexp_split_to_array.

Tags: regex, postgresql, split, delimiter, postgresql-9.1

I have a string look like "P-263-CA" and i want to split it using '-' character using last occurrence so that the out put will be {P-263,CA} using regexp_split_to_array . any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select regexp_split_to_array('P-263-CA', '(-)(?!.*-)');

 regexp_split_to_array 
-----------------------
 {P-263,CA}
(1 row)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cB1nE9/1)